# How to call HTML attribute 'minlength' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code snippet:

```
<div>
      <label for="requiredSize">Required Size 5 : </label>
      <input type="text" name="requiredSize" id="requiredSize" class="required_size" minlength="5" />
</div>
```

I am doing a form validation exercise, and I need to have one of the requirements be based on required size. How can I call the minlength into my JavaScript file to be used, since it does change throughout the form?

I have tried `document.querySelector("minlength")` to try and save it as a variable, but it wasn't being recognized.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewL64 I have used `documnet.querySelector("minlength")` to try and save it as a variable, but it wasnt being recognized

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#requiredSize");
console.log(input.getAttribute('minlength'))
```

```html
<div>
      <label for="requiredSize">Required Size 5 : </label>
      <input type="text" name="requiredSize" id="requiredSize" class="required_size" minlength="5" />
</div>
```